# How do I parse variables in HTML during file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, parsing, php-parser

I'm building a CMS and as part of that any static HTML is being split up into reusable blocks and then saved in one central location. When we need each block we can add it to the string containing the page's HTML code using file_get_contents.

Being CMS some sections of the HTML need to have data loaded from the database. Now I could simply place holders, such as %cmsarea0%, %cmsarea1%, %cmsarea2% and so on, then use str_replace to put the HTML from the database in. However this doesn't seem like the best approach to me.

Ideally I would have several pre-defined variables in my page class, then in the HTML file have PHP to echo that variable out as it's loaded with file_get_contents, however no amount of testing seems to work. My PHP code in the .html file being loaded just gets commented out.

I know this sort of thing is possible as PHPBB use a similar thing, where they wrap their variables in braces and then it's parsed in somehow. But how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you wouldn't want to use `str_replace()`, this seems like the perfect remedy for me.

Try the following

**HTML** - myURL.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv1">%cmsarea1%</div>
        <div id="myDiv2">%cmsarea2%</div>
        <div id="myDiv3">%cmsarea3%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP** - HTMLparse.php

```
$theContent = file_get_contents("myURL.php");

$var1 = $theContent.str_replace("%cmsarea1%", "My first variable");
$var2 = $theContent.str_replace("%cmsarea2%", "My second variable");
$var3 = $theContent.str_replace("%cmsarea3%", "My third variable");
```

Comment: I had seen it parsed other ways in code before, such as PHPBB and it seemed a cleaner way to do it. There could be 10+ areas to replace on a page, and using str_replace just seems a long winded way of doing things. I'm not sure, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't think it's long-winded.  You should be fine to use it.  It'd be faster than regex, that's for sure.

Comment: The "php" in your php block seems to be part javascript... str_replace(search, replace, subject) is what you want. You don't concatanate functions with "." in php.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

You got it all wrong.
The HTML files should not be added using file_get_contents in PHP, but with include. This way, any PHP code within the HTML page will be executed (provided it is wrapped in  tags). Remember that HTML "parts" which are included should have .php extension in order to execute the PHP script contained within.
This is the basics of PHP-HTML templating.

Search the web for "php template website" and learn. 
This is the first result I got, and is pretty usable: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/

Comment: I can't use include as the HTML files are loaded into a variable. Whilst I appreciate the link, what I'm constructing is vastly more complex.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know your level of experience. But, if you say that PHPBB uses similar to what you need, then why not download it and take a peek into the code? It's open source.

Comment: I have, I've even modified it somewhat (no public mods, but enough for my needs), however how it parses the variables in the HTML eludes me unfortunately. It's a complex program. Might be worth posting on their dev forums though... thanks for the idea.